# Mock a method of a class inside action-result C# using moq and nunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

I am doing unit testing of controllers in my asp.net core project. In one section, there is a code like this instantiating an object of class and calling its method.

```
public class ControllerNameController: ControllerBase{
    private IDependency _dependency;
    public ControllerNameController(IDependency dependency){
         _dependency = dependency
    }

       [HttpGet, Route("Get")]
        public ActionResult<dynamic> Get()
        {
            ......

            string someString = "abcd";
            ClassOne classOneObject = new ClassOne(_dependency);
            classOneObject.ClassOneMethod(someString);

            ..........

            return .....

        }
}
```

I am being unable to mock this function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the code. One of the major advantages of unit testing is not to protect you from errors but to help you write better code.

The `ErrorLogHelper` is either a service or a horizontal aspect.

Moq is by design made to mock interfaces or virtual methods. To do that, you need to somehow inject this dependency to the target object.

In this case you need to make this a service dependency, have it implement an interface and inject via property or constructor.

Inline initialization means that the code must run with the unit test, as it is an integral part of the code flow.

```
private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
public IErrorLogHelper logHelper
    public ControllerNameController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IErrorLogHelper logHelper){
         _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
         this.logHelper = logHelper;
    }
```

And in your catch

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string controllerInfo = controller.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName;
                logHelper.ErrorLogToFile(controllerInfo, ex);
            }
```